# Is this uniformly convergent: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+k^2x^2}$ where $x \in (0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am pretty sure that the following is not uniformly convergent: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+k^2x^2}$ where $x \in (0,1)$. I am just having trouble coming up with a counterexample.

Any suggestions? Or am I off-base and this is uniformly convergent? If so, can you explain to me why?

Comment: Suppose you were to compare this sum with $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac 1{k^2x^2}$.  What could you say about this sum?

Comment: *Hint.* In view of the definition, you need that $ \sup_{x \in (0, 1)} | \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+k^2x^2} | $  converges to 0. Is it even finite?

Comment: @SangchulLee: converges to $0$?  I thought uniform convergence meant that it didn't depend on $x$...  Oh, but the limit converges to $0$, not the sum...

Comment: If $(f_n)$ converges uniformly to $f$, then you must have that $\| f_n - f \|_{\mathrm{sup}} = \sup_x |f_n(x) - f(x)|$ converges to 0.

Comment: @abiessu: Comparing it to that sum doesn't seem to get me anywhere since it, too, depends on the value of x. Does it not?

Comment: @BridgeSkier: I just meant that you could use the comparison to bound the sum you are working with and move the $x$ portion out of the sum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)$ be the sequence given by

$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+k^2x^2}$$

Let $\epsilon=\frac12$.  Then, for $x=1/n$ we have

$$|f_n(1/n)|=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+(k/n)^2}\ge \frac{n}{2}>\epsilon$$

Therefore, the convergence is not uniform.